# C# Automapper How to resolve using property from customresolver

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using the following mapping to map my data object to viewmodel object.

ObjectMapper.cs

```
public static class ObjectMapper
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Title,
                       opt => opt.ResolveUsing<TitleValueResolver>())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name,
                       opt => opt.ResolveUsing<NameValueResolver >())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ShortName,
                       opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ShortNameValueResolver >());         
    }
}
```

Parser

```
public class Parser{
public string GetTitle(string title){
/* add some logic */
return title;
}
public string GetName(string title){
/* add some logic */
return name;
}
public string GetShortName(string title){
/* add some logic */
return shortname;
}
}
```

AutoMapperCustomResolvers.cs

```
public class TitleValueResolver : ValueResolver<User, string>
{
    private readonly BaseValueResolver _baseResolver;
    public TitleValueResolver()
    {
        _baseResolver = new BaseValueResolver();
    }

    protected override string ResolveCore(Usersource)
    {
        return _baseResolver.Parser.GetTitle(source.TITLE);
    }
}

public class NameValueResolver : ValueResolver<User, string>
{
    private readonly BaseValueResolver _baseResolver;
    public NameValueResolver()
    {
        _baseResolver = new BaseValueResolver();
    }

    protected override string ResolveCore(Usersource)
    {
        return _baseResolver.Parser.GetName(source.TITLE);
    }
}

public class ShortNameValueResolver : ValueResolver<User, string>
{
    private readonly BaseValueResolver _baseResolver;
    public ShortNameValueResolver()
    {
        _baseResolver = new BaseValueResolver();
    }

    protected override string ResolveCore(Usersource)
    {
        return _baseResolver.Parser.GetShortName(source.TITLE);
    }
}
```

I am using the above code to add logic to the destination property using the separate custom value resolvers. Not sure is this the right approach.

i) Is there a better way to achieve this?

ii) And how to use unity to resolve in case i want to inject some dependency to custom resolver constructor?

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect `TitleValueResolver` to be constructed? It has no default constructor and you do not supply a `ConstructedBy` expression for your mapping configuration. Generally, your example is severely lacking classes... please reduce or provide the missing pieces to turn your example into an mvce.

Comment: @grek40, I have updated my question.

Comment: Is `TypeValueResolver` your new `TitleValueResolver`? How do you expect a value resolver for `MAMAsset` to resolve anything comming from `User` type?

Comment: Sorry. Updated my question. hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to utilize a `ValueResolver`, that resolves multiple source properties into an intermediate data object, which is used to resolve multiple target properties. As an example, I assume the following source, target, intermediate and resolver types:

```
// source
class User
{
    public string UserTitle { get; set; }
}

// target
class UserViewModel
{
    public string VM_Title { get; set; }

    public string VM_OtherValue { get; set; }
}

// intermediate from ValueResolver
class UserTitleParserResult
{
    public string TransferTitle { get; set; }
}

class TypeValueResolver : ValueResolver<User, UserTitleParserResult>
{
    protected override UserTitleParserResult ResolveCore(User source)
    {
        return new UserTitleParserResult { TransferTitle = source.UserTitle };
    }
}
```

You need a target property in order to utilize `opt.ResolveUsing<TypeValueResolver>()`. This means, you can establish a mapping, where an appropriate target property is available.

So, for the moment, lets wrap the result into an appropriate container type:

```
class Container<TType>
{
    public TType Value { get; set; }
}
```

And create a mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, Container<UserViewModel>>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Value, c => c.ResolveUsing<TypeValueResolver>());
```

And another mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserTitleParserResult, UserViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.VM_Title, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.TransferTitle))
    .ForMember(d => d.VM_OtherValue, c => c.Ignore());
```

And another mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
    .BeforeMap((s, d) =>
    {
        Mapper.Map<User, Container<UserViewModel>>(s, new Container<UserViewModel> { Value = d });
    })
    .ForAllMembers(c => c.Ignore());
// establish more rules for properties...
```

The last mapping is a bit special, since it relies on a nested mapping in order to update the destination with values from source via separately configured mapping rules. You can have multiple different transfer mappings for different properties by adding appropriate intermediate mappings and calls in `BeforeMap` of the actual mapped type. The properties that are handled in other mappings need to be ignored, since AutoMapper doesn't know about the mapping in `BeforeMap`

Small usage example:

```
var user = new User() { UserTitle = "User 1" };

// create by mapping
UserViewModel vm1 = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(user);

UserViewModel vm2 = new UserViewModel() { VM_Title = "Title 2", VM_OtherValue = "Value 2" };
// map source properties into existing target
Mapper.Map(user, vm2);
```

Dunno if this helps you. There might be better ways if you rephrase your question to describe your initial problem instead of what you suspect to be a solution.

Comment: i have updated my question. Hope it will be clear now.

Comment: Sorry, Unity is out of scope for me, didn't use it yet.

Comment: Hi, basically i am trying to to use ValueResolver that resolve on one single source property into an intermediate object which will resolve multiple target properties.